# Array of objects, remove the array after push, keep objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, angularjs

Im trying to push my array of objects into variable, but all i I recieve is Array in Array, or single object.

```
  myObject = {
          id: id,
          items: [],
          boolean: true,  
        }
    
    myArray = [{1}, {2}, {3}]
```

I tried `myObject.items.push(myArray[0])` but this returns only first object. Without 0 its double array.

What i want is

```
myObject = {
              id: id,
              items: [{1}, {2}, {3}],
              boolean: true,  
            }
```

Comment: `.concat()` not `.push()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to want to do here is set the entire array as the new value like this:

```
myObject.items = myArray
```

If you want to take the immutable approach then you can copy it like this:

```
myObject.items = [...myArray]
```

**Edit:**

If you want to add items (and not just complete overwrite) to `myObject.items` then you should do this:

```
myObject.items = [...myObject.items, ...myArray]
```

That will add your new array items to the end of the current items array, you could also do this to add them to the start:

```
myObject.items = [...myArray, ...myObject.items]
```

Comment: This only works when `myObject.items` is empty or the content can be destroyed.

Comment: @Andreas Mine array is empty, but thank you for improvements!

Comment: @Andreas good point, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
myObject.items.push(...myArray)
```

Comment: Also works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Andreas commented another solution is to use concat. Concat is similar to `push`. But it doesn't actually change the array it returns a new one.

```
const x = []
console.log(x.concat(3)) // prints [3]
console.log(x) // prints []
```

This behavior is often desired as it prevents "side effects" from occurring

It also doesn't just append items to an array, it only does this if the item is not an array. If it is an array it will merge the two arrays

```
const x = [1,2,3]
console.log(x.concat([4,5,6]) // prints [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

so a solution here is

```
myObject.items = myObject.items.concat(myArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//object
myObject={
    id:1,
    items:[],
    boolean: true

}
//concat  
myArray = [ 1,2,3];
  myObject.items += myArray;
  console.log(myObject.items);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).